# Write a single line from one process and consume a single line from another

Tags: python, bash, sh, named-pipes, fifo

I have a loop from python that writes proxies to a file, one per line. That file is later used from a bash script via `curl -x $PROXY`, line by line using `cat proxies.txt`.

Could this approach be improved by launching the two scripts at the same time, and using a named pipe that can be consumed by `cat` only when python writes a new line/new proxy?

In my mind, I'd write something like

```
f = open('/tmp/proxies', 'w') # but this call is blocking!
for proxy in ...:
    f.write(proxy)
```

and

```
for PROXY in $(cat /tmp/proxies); do curl -x $PROXY example.com; done
```

Comment: Why not starting this curl call inside the python script? Or using a python curl API.

Comment: @languitar the approach you suggest leave my code sequential, while I'd like to start the two process simultaneously

Comment: A FIFO does not provide persistence.  Writing to a FIFO blocks if there is no reader.  Launch your reader from inside your Python program before starting to write, but make sure you launch the reader as a separate process, and do not wait for it to finish before starting to write.

Comment: As an aside, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: In python 3 you could launch curl requests in parallel easily using [`concurrent.future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html).

Comment: Or consider just starting a new subprocess from the writer script instead of writing the stuff to an external file at all.  You don't need Python 3 for that.

Comment: By the way, this is not related to the use of Python.  If you build a Bash script that writes to a FIFO, and afterwards tries to read from it, the write will block and nothing else will happen (because the script will never reach the statement supposed to read).  Either the writer or the reader has to be started in parallel and will block until the other one is started.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of comments about the blocking of the FIFO; I won't repeat them, but the main issue is: when no process reads, the writing process is blocked.

The code you might be looking for is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
python the_python_script.py &  # start in the background
tail -f /tmp/proxies| while read px; do 
    curl -x $px example.com
done
```

There should probably be some logic to terminate the bash script when the python script dies.